# XM cloud setup error: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem xxxx: The host compute system service has disconnected unexpectedly

Tags: docker

I'm getting this error while running ./up.ps1.

[image]

Docker is running windows container.
IIS stopped.

Comment: Did you check if any Firewall is blocking? Disable the firewall and try again.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give more information here? Its going to be almost impossible to know what the issue is from that screenshot.

Comment: 1. cloned fresh xmc solution from https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head

2. stopped IIS, stopped all solr services.

3. run these to commands
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All

4.  .\init.ps1 -InitEnv -LicenseXmlPath C:\license\license.xml -AdminPassword b

5. .\up.ps1

got error on 5th step
also no firewall enabled

Answer (score 0):

Found multiple possible solutions as below -

1. Run Windows Powershell as "Administrator" and run the following commands to enable containers and Hyper -V. Restart machine after executing the second command -

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All
>
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
> –All

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431890/error-response-from-daemon-hcsshimcreatecomputesystem-the-virtual-machine-co

2. This issue can be due to not having enabled Hyper-V Services in Windows Features.

   Searching Turn Windows features on or off led to enable this option, which worked after reboot.
   Reference - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40720

Comment: It didn't worked, also I've already run these commands before setup.